# How to negate part of a photo?

Tags: images, image-editing

Is there an easy way to make a part of a photo negative with computer? Is there a good image viewer that does that.(esp open-source)

Comment: What OS?​​​​​​​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) can do that.

See [Invert](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-invert.html):

> The Invert command inverts all the pixel colors and brightness values in the current layer, as if the image were converted into a negative. Dark areas become bright and bright areas become dark. Hues are replaced by their complementary colors.

Comment: *> I think your question should be in photography site not here.*   @codescope, actually no; this would not fit at [*Photography*](http://photo.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, it would be great – in the future – to expand your answers to more than just a link. Please give context where necessary and explain how the link answers the question.

Comment: Also, GIMP is not an image-viewer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to make a part of a photo negative with computer?

Windows’ own MSPaint can invert a photo via *Image⇨Invert Colors* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

> Is there a good image viewer that does that.(esp open-source)?

It’s [not OSS](http://www.osalt.com/irfanview), but [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is one of the best image-viewers available. It can invert colors via *Image⇨Negative*.